# How to access main window element from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can help with this issue. I have a popup iframe using lytebox. I would like it that when I click a link in my iframe with the class `mylink` that it executes the AJAX call and update a `div` in my main window with the `id="mydiv"`.
I know how to do the `onclick` events and the ajax call but I do not know how to access the `mydiv` from the main window and update it with the content.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `window.parent.document` to access the parent document from the iframe.

jQuery allows you to [specify a context](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) for searches, so you could then do:

```
$(myselector, window.parent.document);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For other users, the jquery code is $('#elementid', window.parent.document).html();